# How to deploy same firebase cloud function under different regions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Currently we are using express framework with in firebase cloud functions and we would like to have same api distributed on different regions.

Currently this is how it is exported now.

```
exports.api = functions.region("asia-east2").https.onRequest(app);
```

As our users are distributed all over globally, is there any way we can make sure the api request hits the nearest region function for faster access and low latency?

Comment: I'm not expert in Firebase, I know better GCP. But for deploying in several region, you have to deploy several time (or perform a loop with the region in param). However, in GCP, it's not possible to set a global load balancer to route the query to different function. I fear there is the same thing with firebase.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Cloud Functions deployed through Firebase have exactly the same properties as with Cloud (they are essentially the same product, Firebase just adds tools and APIs on top).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere If we deploy multiple functions for each region, how can we make sure the request is serviced from the nearest location?

DougStevenson - Anyway to redirect from firebase.json hosting rewrites?

Comment: So, if the underlying platform is the same, there isn't loadbalancing. The name of the function is per region and you can't route to another name function

Comment: ok, question is how we can setup the nearest cloud function is selected for a location?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more complex that one might think (at least to my humble knowledge), the short answer is you can't do it by default, this is more like HTTPS load balancer.

Your functions are unique, "the trick" is to route your user to the client deployed on the nearest region. Google Cloud DNS is your friend here (but a not as cool friend as AWS Route53, I left a blog post to get you started). You can get the nearest nameserver taking advantage of the anycast network, but that is as far as you go. I'm not sure what are your implementation details but these resources helped to get started:

- https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-load-balancer-example
- https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#performance_and_timing
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws/

Again, it's not about routing the functions, it's about routing the traffic to the client that point to that function, sadly in my case, I end up using AWS Route 53's latency/geo so, I don't have too many details here.